# What happens if there are no transactions?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, mining-profitability

Could you please explain what would happen without transactions?
Let's say people stop s(p)ending for a while for whatever reason.
What miners would do if there are no transactions? Will they just keep a copy of blockchain and have no reward for approving transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A miner can mine an otherwise completely empty block, and still collect the award of 12.5 BTC for completing a block.